# Add CSS dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

I tried the following JQuery method to replace CSS values dynamically but it doesn't work. Any idea which part is wrong?

In my html:

```
<div class="svg">
     <button class="type_1"></button>
</div>
```

My current CSS that needs to be replaced dynamically:

```
svg .type_1    
{
    stroke: rgb(255, 128, 0);
    fill: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

My current method which doesn't work:

```
 $('.svg .type_' + list.id).css({
        stroke: list.hex_color,
        fill: list.hex_color
 });
```

Comment: typo `.svg` <--> `svg` ?

Comment: Although your `div` has the `svg` class, the CSS shouldn't be applied as it is targetting an `svg` element

Comment: @phuzi I just want to replace current fixed css svg .type_1 { rgb... } with dynamically added css

Comment: Only remove the dot:  `$('.svg .type_' + list.id)` → ` $('svg .type_' + list.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have concatenation problem, you have to wrap the css in quotes

```
$('.svg .type_' + list.id).css({
        'stroke': list.hex_color,
        'fill': list.hex_color
 });
```

Comment: I tried this method, its not working, how do I check this dynamically added CSS is served at that webpage? I want to see whether it overwrite the initial CSS